# HTML/CSS: Quando clico no link não vai para o ponto certo da página

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Tenho uma página que possui um menu no topo simples que possui alguns links que levam o usuário direto para a seção referente à esse link:

```
<style>
    nav {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background-color: black;
    }

    section {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
    }

    #sec1 {  
        background-color: red;  
    }

    #sec2 {
        background-color: blue;
    }

    #sec3 {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>

<nav>
    <a href="#sec1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#sec2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#sec3">Link 3</a>
</nav>

<section id="sec1">
    ...
</section>

<section id="sec2">
    ...
</section>

<section id="sec3">
    ...
</section>
```

Esse menu de navegação está fixado no topo, e por conta disso quando vou direto para a seção ele encobre parte do conteúdo, gerando assim a necessidade do usuário rolar a página para ver esse trecho. Minha dúvida é: existe alguma maneira de controlar essa rolagem com CSS ou JavaScript? Pensei em fazer isso dando um padding-top em todas as seções, porém não me parece ser a maneira correta.

Comment: não entendi o porquê dos votos negativos, cometi algum erro na pergunta?

Comment: coloca um `padding-top;`no `body`, regula de acordo com o que vc goste. `padding-top: 70px`, por exemplo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De qualquer forma é preciso colocar um `padding-top` no `body` da mesma altura da `nav`, senão a primeira `section` ficará sobreposta.

```
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding-top: 60px;
}
```

Veja que resetei também o `margin` para eliminar o espaçamento padrão do `body`.

Com um JavaScript você consegue calcular a posição do scroll da janela e posicionar a `section` logo abaixo da `nav`:

```js
const menu = document.querySelectorAll("nav a");
for(let i of menu){
   i.onclick = function(){
      let nav_height = document.querySelector("nav").clientHeight; // altura da nav
      setTimeout(function(){
         let scrol = window.scrollY; // posição do scroll da janela
         window.scrollTo(0, scrol-nav_height);
      }, 10);
   }
}
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
padding-top: 60px;
}
nav {
     width: 100%;
     height: 60px;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     background-color: black;
 }

a{color: white}

 section {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100vh;
 }

 #sec1 {  
     background-color: red;  
 }

 #sec2 {
     background-color: blue;
 }

 #sec3 {
     background-color: green;
 }
```

```html
<nav>
    <a href="#sec1">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#sec2">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#sec3">Link 3</a>
</nav>

<section id="sec1">
    sec1
</section>

<section id="sec2">
    sec2
</section>

<section id="sec3">
    sec3
</section>
```

Comment: Obrigado Sam, funcionou perfeito!